# What do people in Hong Kong say when you are approaching a counter to buy something?

Tags: cantonese, phrase, topolect, spoken

I've often found myself at the typical 7/11 waiting in line to ring out, and almost every time the cashier will say something right before I am to purchase. It sounds something like "lao wei" but I cannot figure out what it is despite how much I've tried to search on the internet for what it is they're saying. I'm thinking its something like "來。。。" but I haven't a clue. Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely a contraction of "下一位" (next customer please)

下一位/**ha**a6 j**at1** wai6^2/  --> 下~位/**haat1** wai6^2/

Comment: That sounds right. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Funny, must be the the way of saying 下  in the South. When I was in Vietnam, Ha Long Bay, our nice Vietnamese guide explained: "Ha Long" means "where the dragon came down" I immediately understood: 下龙